# Windows Server 2008 not accepting connections to Server Programs

Tags: windows-server-2008, tcp, connection

A company which our agency works for got a Windows Server 2008.
I've had the job to install an FTP-Server (FileZilla Server) on this Windows Server 2008.

Now my problem is that the server does not accept **most** of the connections.
VPN-Connections to this server work [even from outside], but ftp from outside the local network does not work.

I've also written a little tool to test which connections the server accepts - it accepts connections from inside the network but not from outside the network. The router is properly configured, the packets are even visible in wireshark on that server, but the server does not seem to accept them if they're coming from outside the local network, i.e. No ACK.

If they come from inside everything is fine.

I am not sure why but i think it might have something to do with the fact that it has 2 NICs.

It has "Routing and Ras" as a role installed and i've deactivated even the whole firewall for the tests. No results

Would be happy for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the NIC-Drivers did it...